# How to clip a vector feature to the extent of an existing raster dataset using arcpy

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster, arcpy, vector, clip

I have a clipped raster dataset with polylines (from the contour tool) overlayed (see attached).  I am trying to clip the polylines to the extent of the raster dataset, which seems simple enough, but I've tried multiple things and can't seem to get it to work.  I will eventually need to code this using arcpy but I think for now, just a nudge in the right direction as to which tool will accomplish this will help me for now.

Thanks.

P.S.  I am using ArcInfo 10.0

[image: clipPolylinesToRasterExtent]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the dataset extent as a polygon geometry with the clip tool, as in the [Using geometries in geoprocessing tools](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Using_geometry_objects_with_geoprocessing_tools/002z0000001z000000/) example.

```py
import arcpy

pnt_array = arcpy.Array()
extent = arcpy.Raster(in_raster).extent
pnt_array.add(extent.lowerLeft)
pnt_array.add(extent.lowerRight)
pnt_array.add(extent.upperRight)
pnt_array.add(extent.upperLeft)

poly = arcpy.Polygon(pnt_array)

arcpy.Clip_analysis(in_lines, poly, "out_dataset")
```

Comment: Thank you!!  Before I saw this post, I was able to at least manually do it within Arc, but it sure seems like my way is slightly convoluted.  I created a dummy shapefile and then constructed a polygon with the editor tools which outlined the boundary of the raster data.  Then I ran the clip tool on the polylines using this dummy shapefile as what it should clip them too.  I got an error, but then I used feature to polygon and used the result of this as the shapefile for the polylines to be clipped to and it worked!!  I will need arcpy so thanks for that!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way to do this.

First get the extent of the raster image.

set it as environment extent property

Then use the copy feature instead of clip analysis , for example

```
arcpy.env.extent = arcpy.Extent(-107.0, 38.0, -104.0, 40.0)
...some code here to ...
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(shapefile,outFeatureClass)
```

Comment: Note that whilst this is generally faster than using `Clip_analysis`, any features that intersect the extent bounding box will be selected "in full" and won't actually be clipped back to the bounding box edge.